# How do you test a SignalR application (load + functional combined) hosted on an Azure Appservice

Tags: c#, .net, load-testing, asp.net-core-signalr, azure-signalr

How do you test a SignalR application (load + functional combined) hosted on an Azure Appservice
We are building a SignalR application for questionpolling to the audience during events and congresses (in real-time).
We expect sessions of 1000-2000 active concurrent users, that means most of them will connect simultaneously.
This will cause heavy load under short periods of time.
We want to simulate x amount of unique clients that will connect simultaneously.
For example 1000 users connecting during 30 seconds.
Languages and signalR packages:
The app is built with .NET Core 2.2 with a React frontend.
*SignalR package (.NET)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core (1.1.0)
*SignalR package (npm)
    @aspnet/signalr (1.1.4)
Azure setup
We are running our app on a Azure Appservice with Azure SQL DB.
We are using Azure SignalR Service and will scale according to our customers need.

Testing
We have tried to loadtest with Jmeter, and have done GUI tests (with Selenium in small scale 100-200 users). We have also run an in app test that creates hubconnections via a javascript loop. But we can not ensure that our application will work with 1000-2000 active connections.
My question is how does one test an application of this type and confirm its. I can not be the first one building an application like this.

Answer (score 5):

The most obvious approaches are:

1. [Crank, the tool for SignalR performance testing from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/signalr-connection-density-testing-with-crank)
2. [`signalr-tester`](https://github.com/emtecinc/signalr-tester)
3. JMeter should be a good option as well check out [How to Load Test Async Requests with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-load-test-async-requests-with-jmeter) article for more information, it can be also integrated with Selenium via [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/)